# Начальное масштабирование не адаптивной верстки на смартфонах

Tags: масштабирование, адаптивная-верстка, html, css

Здравствуйте.

Сайт сверстан не адаптивно, но для некоторых элементов прописано особое поведение на смартфонах через media queries (часть элементов скрывается, изменяется лейаут и т.п.).
Задан <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">.

Вопрос:
на смартфонах в Хроме и в Opera Mobile все ок, но, например, в IE и в экзотических браузерах типа Dolphin начальный масштаб слишком большой, т.е. приходится щипком уменьшать размер страницы. Как добиться на этих браузерах такого же поведения, как в Хроме, т.е. чтобы после загрузки без масштабирования страница вписывалась в размеры окна устройства?

Благодарю за советы.

Comment: К сожалению, ответ дан в комментарии. У комментариев нет "галки".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак, смысла тестировать под "не webkit" браузеры на мобильных нет никакого. Вероятно, ваш dolphin незнает, что такое viewport в силу своей убогости. Проверьте в хроме и сафари на ошибки w3c. Про остальное забудьте - это проблемы браузеров.

Answer (score 1):

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Или

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
```

Или

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: @David Kern, используйте, пожалуйста, кириллицу.